# How to remove spaces between html code in csv file during download time

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to remove the spaces in adv_text field. It contain HTML code so much spaces occur.Before download I want to remove space

```
public function downloadadv()
{
    $today_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $this->load->dbutil(); 
    $this->load->model('admin/adv_model');  
    $query=$this->adv_model->advdetail(); 

    foreach($query->result() as $name) 
    {
        $text=replace($name->adv_text,' ','');
        echo $text;
    }
}
```

here before download I used replace but no effect.

Comment: What is `replace` ?  Over Here

Comment: i want to replace double space to single space thats i mean it

Answer (score 1):

To remove multiple occurrences of white space characters in a string an convert them all into single spaces, use this [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$text = $name->adv_text;
$text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);//Remove space and tab.
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

For just spaces, use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$text = $name->adv_text;
$text = str_replace(' ', '', $text);//Remove only spaces
```

Comment: i used both method but no change

Comment: Can you please give some string example which is passed from both function but no change as you expect?

Comment: actually i didnt understand

Comment: $text=$name->adv_text;
                    $text1=preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$text);
                     echo $text1;

Comment: For example:  string = ' hello        '. so ' hello         ' is string now in case you which string that having space and you want to remove it.

Comment: kk ...its html code.........................................................................................<div class='section ' id='section_30459'>

  <div class='inner portfolio'>

    

    <div class='inner_inner'>

    

    

    

    <div rel='' class='header '>

    

      <h3><span id='edit_title_cv_section_30459' class='' >Custom Block </span></h3>



    </div>



    <div class='body ' 

      id='section_30459_body' style="">

Comment: long html code...in betwwen this lots space occurs.so i want to remove this spacess

Comment: None of other examples may this work for you, so I've used this one:

trim(preg_replace('/[\s\t\n\r\s]+/', ' ', $text));

This replaces all tabs, new lines, double spaces etc to simple 1 space.
Let me know for more help.

Comment: jeni, If above all given solution are not working then we have last option to check by passed my self and for that you need to share your file which contain that values(couple of string) and what you require to remove(spaces or other?). I will check it at my end and give you solution if possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85270/discussion-between-jeni-and-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead of `replace()`.